# How to fix an unexpected EOF while parsing?

Tags: python, statistics

I am completely stuck on this one, just trying to get the OLS summary on this data & it continually comes up with the error of "PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (, line 1) lag_eps ~ return"

Can anyone point to where I am going wrong here?

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9AYw.png)
[My Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwvT5.png)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). [do not post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Does it work if you rename your `return` column to something else? Patsy is unable to parse your formula definition, and whilst I'm not familiar with the patsy formula model, `return` may well be causing trouble as it's a keyword.

Comment: Or perhaps you could use the patsy [quote](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builtins-reference.html#patsy.builtins.Q) mechanic to quote that column rather than rename it: `"lag_eps ~ Q('return')"`?

Comment: Thank you so much guys, this was really helpful!